# ask without log in or entering email in DWQA (wordpress plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

IN [`QW` question & Answer](http://www.designwall.com/guide/dw-question-answer-plugin/) ( **wordpress** **plugin** ) ,how can user add question without registering(log in) or entering their email address ?

I want that all user(guest) can be able to ask their questions without entering their email address or even registering.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I just resolved it.

DWQA version 1.3.3

You have to replace the function

```
 function dwqa_require_field_submit_question()
```

with your own version. You find the old function at line 79 in your template-functions.php in the plugin folder.

Just removing the function from the queue will make it impossible to add new questions. So you just add the adjusted version of the function to your functions.php in your theme folder and and remove the standard function and add the adjusted function.

Add following to your functions.php:

```
function dwqa_require_field_submit_question_adjusted(){
?>
<input type="hidden" name="dwqa-action" value="dwqa-submit-question" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'dwqa-submit-question-nonce-#!' ); ?>

<?php  
    $subscriber = get_role( 'subscriber' );
?>
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! dwqa_current_user_can( 'post_question' ) ) { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="login-type" id="login-type" value="sign-up" autocomplete="off">
<div class="question-register clearfix">
    <label for="user-email"><?php _e( 'You need an account to submit question and get answers. Create one:','dwqa' ) ?></label>
    <div class="register-email register-input">
        <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Type your email','dwqa' ) ?>" name="user-email">
    </div>
    <div class="register-username register-input">
        <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" placeholder="Choose an username" name="user-name-signup" id="user-name-signup">
    </div>
    <div class="login-switch"><?php _e( 'Already a member?','dwqa' ) ?> <a class="credential-form-toggle" href="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Log In','dwqa' ) ?></a></div>
</div>

<div class="question-login clearfix dwqa-hide">
    <label for="user-name"><?php _e( 'Login to submit your question','dwqa' ) ?></label>
    <div class="login-username login-input">
        <input type="text" size="20" value="" class="input" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Type your username','dwqa' ) ?>" id="user-name" name="user-name">
    </div>
    <div class="login-password login-input">
        <input type="password" size="20" value="" class="input" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Type your password','dwqa' ) ?>" id="user-password" name="user-password">
    </div>
    <div class="login-switch"><?php _e( 'Not yet a member?','dwqa' ) ?> <a class="credential-form-toggle" href="javascript:void( 0 );" title="<?php _e( 'Register','dwqa' ) ?>"><?php _e( 'Register','dwqa' ) ?></a></div>
</div>
<?php } else if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && dwqa_current_user_can( 'post_question' ) ) { ?>
//Here was the old code which had shown the E-mail input and login information
<?php  }
}
```

This function will replace the old function

```
 function dwqa_require_field_submit_question()
```

Now just remove the old function and add the new to the queue in your functions.php :)

```
remove_action( 'dwqa_submit_question_ui', 'dwqa_require_field_submit_question' );
add_action( 'dwqa_submit_question_ui', 'dwqa_require_field_submit_question_adjusted' );
```

That is it :). Maybe not the best way, but it avoids changing the plugin code.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
//Removes BuddyBar from non-admins only
function splen_remove_admin_bar() { if( !is_super_admin() )
add_filter( ‘show_admin_bar’, ‘__return_false’ );
}
add_action(‘wp’, ‘splen_remove_admin_bar’);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.